# How to read next line from a text file

Tags: android, text-files

I want to read several lines from a text file. These line should be displayed one by one, when I click the next button. I am able to store the strings in a file and read the first line. But when I try to read the next line using the next button, it stops working. Can anybody tell me a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

I have defined the following,

```
BufferedReader buffreader;      
String line;
String fav;
StringBuilder text;   
InputStream instream;     
String favQuote0;
```

This is in my oncreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_save);
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();        

    try {
        // open the file for reading
        InputStream instream = openFileInput("myfilename.txt");

        // if file the available for reading
        if (instream != null) {             
            // prepare the file for reading
            InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
            BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);   

            while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {       
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');                  
                fav = text.toString();             
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {}

    TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv1.setText(fav);   
}
```

This is my next button

```
public void next (View view1) {         
    try {
        // open the file for reading
        InputStream instream = openFileInput("myfilename.txt");

        // if file the available for reading
        if (instream != null) {
            while (( line = buffreader.readLine()) != null) {               
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');                  
                fav = text.toString();             
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {}

    TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv1.setText(fav);
}
```

Comment: Did you see any error in LogCat?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this. This i working for me

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
StringBuffer bf = new StringBuffer();
String json = reader.readLine();
try {
do {

    bf.append(json);
    json = reader.readLine();
}while (json != null);
wt.flush();
wt.close();
Log.d("LOG", " read line output "+new String(bf)+" json "+json);
reader.close();     
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace(); }
```

wt is the bufferedwriter which i used to write line. I read from reader and write into file stored locally.

Comment: What is Wt? we have to define it? it gives me an error so I couldn't run it. Will it read from the last position if run it? Thanks

Comment: I found the problem. It was a problem related to writing in to the file. We have to write to the file in Append mode, other wise all the file content will be rewritten. The code is as follows.                                                         OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("myfilename.txt",MODE_APPEND));                                                                       for reading my code works fine!Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers do it the wrong way. I will post a description below my code. This is the proper way of doing it.

```
private int mCurrentLine;
private ArrayList<String> mLines;
private TextView mTextView;
private Button mButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_save);

    mCurrentLine = -1;
    mLines = new ArrayList<String>();
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    try {
        readLinesAndSaveToArrayList();
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    setTextAndIncrement();

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setTextAndIncrement();
        }
    });
}

private void readLinesAndSaveToArrayList() throws IOException {
    File file = new File("myfilename.txt");

    if (!file.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException("myfilename.txt was unable to locate");
    }

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String line;

    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        mLines.add(line);
    }

    bufferedReader.close();
}

private void setTextAndIncrement() {
    if (mCurrentLine == mLines.size() - 1) {
        return;
    }

    mCurrentLine++;
    mTextView.setText(mLines.get(mCurrentLine));
}
```

What I do is cache the file's contents in a scalable `ArrayList`. Each line will be assigned to an index in the array, eg. 0, 1, 2 and so on.

`mCurrentLine` takes care of positioning in the array. It starts at -1 because there is no current line. In the `setTextAndIncrement()` it will be set to 0, which in the array is the first index (the first line). The continuous calls will increment the position and take the next lines. If you come to the limit I have put in a check that looks if the `mCurrentLine` is equal to the max size of lines (mLines.size() - 1, a - 1 because arrays starts from 0 instead of 1).

Other than that I would advice you to use full length names on methods and variables; there is no need to keep them short, it will only make reading them harder. XML should also only contain low letters instead of camelCases.

Comment: This doen't work for me. When I click the button I see nothing

Comment: Don't put negative comments in others answers when your solution also dosen't work!

Comment: @user1995307 There is no flaw in my code, you must have done something wrong. Do you mean the TextView does not get updated? You might want to check logcat that you do not receive any exception. FileNotFoundException is not a Runtime exception so it is very much likely the "myfilename.txt" could not be located and it will not crash. Consider change FileNotFoundException to RuntimeException. Also please do not say other's code does not work if you have not exhausted every possibility it may.

Answer (score -2):

```
try {
// open the file for reading
InputStream instream = new FileInputStream("myfilename.txt");

 // if file the available for reading
 if (instream != null) {
 // prepare the file for reading
 InputStreamReader inputreader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
 BufferedReader buffreader = new BufferedReader(inputreader);

  String line;

   // read every line of the file into the line-variable, on line at the time
   while (buffreader.hasNext()) {
 line = buffreader.readLine();
// do something with the line 
}

}
 } catch (Exception ex) {
  // print stack trace.
} finally {
 // close the file.
 instream.close();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. It i showing an error "The method hasNext() is undefined for the type BufferedReader" what is this? If we give new for input stream reader and buffered reader will it read from the next line or it will start from begining again. I want to read it from last position.

Comment: @sachin Have you given any link?

Comment: BufferedReader does not have any method called hasNext().

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html